# Silhouette score for optimal k value (k prototype in python)

Tags: python, clustering

I am trying to cluster using k prototypes algorithm as my data has both categorical and continuous variables

I found this answer explaining the elbow method with k prototype
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56218269/9543171

How can I use silhouette score instead of cost for finding optimal k value in k prototype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it's too late, but I found a good resource for your question - [silhouette score for k-prototype](https://codinginfinite.com/silhouette-coefficient-for-k-modes-and-k-prototypes-clustering/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).